# Not sure of the right way of calling multiple functions. I just need simple syntax help

Tags: jquery, syntax, jquery-validate

New to jQuery. Need help with simple syntax.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    jQuery.validator.addMethod("phoneUS", function (phone_number, element) {
        phone_number = phone_number.replace(/\s+/g, "");
        return this.optional(element) || phone_number.length > 9 && phone_number.match(/^(1-?)?(\([2-9]\d{2}\)|[2-9]\d{2})-?[2-9]\d{2}-?\d{4}$/);
    }, "Please specify a valid phone number");
    $("#networx_affiliate").validate({
        rules: {
            service_name: "required"
        }
    }).ajaxForm({
        url: '**********',
        target: '#output',
        type: 'post',
        dataType: 'xml',
        success: function processXml(responseXML) {
            // 'responseXML' is the XML document returned by the server; we use 
            // jQuery to extract the content of the message node from the XML doc 
            $(xml).find("affiliateresponse").each(function () {
                $("#output").append($(this).find("successCode") + "<br />");
                $("#output").append($(this).find("errormessage") + "<br />");
            });
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

I got a validation form plugin and a ajax form plugin. Please what is the right way to call them. cause the way i have them now ajax doesn't seem to work.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want to call ajax method after form validation you can done like this

```
$("#networx_affiliate").validate({
        submitHandler: function (form) {
            CallAjaxMethod();
        },

        rules: {
            service_name: "required"
        }
});

function CallAjaxMethod()
{
    $.ajax({
        url: 'https://api.networx.com',
        target: '#output',
        type: 'post',
        dataType: 'xml',
        success: function processXml(responseXML) {
            // 'responseXML' is the XML document returned by the server; we use 
            // jQuery to extract the content of the message node from the XML doc 
            $(xml).find("affiliateresponse").each(function () {
                $("#output").append($(this).find("successCode") + "<br />");
                $("#output").append($(this).find("errormessage") + "<br />");
            });
        }
    });

}
```

Comment: Thank you, very much. It makes alot of sense to me now. But i just realized that i cant do ajax crossdomain xml requests.

Answer (score 0):

.validate() returns validator not form object.  Try calling .ajaxForm() first then .validate().